# Fetch and output binary data from a file

Tags: c++

I've been trying in several ways to tackle this problem, but it is likely that I misunderstood how I'm supposed to actually read the data from the file, here's what I came up with:

```
#define LENGTH 0xF8C
.
.
.
unsigned short int eval_checksum()
{
  unsigned short int checksum=255;
  int seekhead=0x2598;
  char * buffer = new char [10000];
  ifstream binaryFile(SAVEFILE_NAME, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
  binaryFile.read (buffer,LENGTH); //how does it read???
  checksum-=int(buffer[0]);
  return checksum;
}
```

which is obviously not correct. Before this I tried with a for loop

```
#define SEEK seekhead+i
unsigned short int eval_checksum()
{
  ...
  for(int i=0;i<0xF8C;i++)
  {
    binaryFile.read(buffer,SEEK);
    checksum-=buffer[0];
    cout<<checksum<<endl;
  }
}
```

Again, no luck. I don't need to store the whole thing in a buffer, so I figured I could just store the last byte on an array of size 1. The only thing I need to do is to sequentially read every byte and calculate the checksum accordingly (start from 255 and subtract the value of each byte).

I managed to successfully locate a byte in a specific offset and change it, but I couldn't really read and output what's in there.

What would be an elegant way to read each byte?

Comment: What about `binaryFile >> buffer`?

Comment: it did something, but I don't understand what happened. I tried to output the data stored in the buffer but it's completely different from the original file.

Comment: Would it be possible to say "I want you to store offset 0x2598 in a char variable" and then use that as a buffer, modify the value in the buffer and then write it back into the file? That would make it so much more convenient and easier to just modify values from specific offsets of my choice without a massive mostly useless buffer that holds unnecessary data

Comment: I don't get exactly what you are doing with `SEEK`. If you iterate over `i` and `SEEK` is a makro of `seekhead+i`, then this means you read an increasing amount of bytes in each iteration, which is kind of strange. In any case, I'd strongly recommend not to use makros like that. Avoid them when possible. Make `LENGTH` a proper global constant (use `constexpr`) or better make it a proper variable, as argument or member or similar.

Comment: @Aziuth I think I misunderstood how read works, I was trying to make it read a portion of the file from offset 0x2598 to offset 0x3523, but now I found out it requires a fixed length because that value describes how "large" the portion is, but even if I succeded that way it would be cumbersome and not particularly efficient, I don't even need to store everything in a buffer, there is only a specific portion that I am supposed to edit without trashing the binary file

Comment: Ah, kinda suspected that. Yes, the second argument of `ifstream::read` is the amount of bytes to read, and it automatically advances. Note that if you want to jump to a certain offset without reading the data in between, you can advance using `ifstream::seekg`, as demonstrated here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-position-with-seekg-in-cpp-language-file-handling/

Comment: @Aziuth it outputs garbled text whenever it's dealing with a binary file, if it's a plain text file it's fine. What gives? And yes, I have opened the file as a `ios::binary`

Comment: Can't say anything without an example file and program, but most likely you convert wrongly. I recommend that first thing you write a loop that simply prints the integer values of each byte in the file and then compare it with what you see in an editor (like Notepad++ with hex reader plugin). But still, how do you convert your bytes into your data? Are you sure it's the right type and right size?

Comment: The file I need to edit is literally a RAM dump. Opening it as a binary should let C++ treat it as such, and by the way, it does actually read the file properly and the for loops you suggested does appear to do a perfect job, but the problem arises the moment I try writing back to the file, it just outputs wrong data (only 0x30 or 0x31 apparently)